# OOXML - Excel Table, PivotTable, How to update data & refresh source correctly

Tags: ruby, openxml

What is the cleanest and simplest way to bind a range of data dynamically to a pivottable? I have dynamically added data to existing excel .xlsx files for several years now with a ruby component I wrote, and it's pretty easy.

When I add a pivottable to the mix, there are a lot more xml files and references to the pivottable and its data. It looks like you can bind a pivottable to a named range, a dynamic named range, or an excel table. What direction is the simplest if the goal is to be able to add data to a sheet and expect to be able to just refresh the pivottable for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the free e-book [Open XML - The Markup Explained](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15359).  It has a section that addresses what is needed in your xlsx file for a Pivot Table that starts on Page 75.

Comment: Yeah, I've glanced over that, but did not read it in detail. On second glance, it DOES provide some good insight. However, the premise of that section appears to assume you want to gen the .xlx from scratch. I can certainly do that, but would prefer to use an existing .xlsx as a "template", update/replace the data and tell the .xlsx to refresh the pivottable.

Comment: One strategy you can use to help you learn what to update in your "template" approach, is to take your template file and save it as File1.xlsx, then change one piece of data and save this as File2.xlsx.  Then run the Open XML 2.0 Producitvity Tool and click the compare files button - this will show you where the files differ and will generate you C# code of the differences.  If Im stumped on any openXml head scratchers, that is the first thing I do to try and learn what is going on.

Comment: Oops - just realized you are doing ruby - not c# - well the tool and strategy are still helpful - it is a true XML diff tool and highlights sections side by side on how they are different - so you can know how to go in and change the XML.  You can likely just update table data and the client and pivot table will do all of the updates for you when the file is opened.  [Download link for the tool and SDK is here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124).  The help file with the SDK has some very helpful examples to help you understand OpenXML also.

Comment: Yeah, that will be very helpful - downloading now. When I update/replace/add rows to the sheet holding the data, how do I tell the spreadsheet the new range of data? Am I better off with a named range or an excel table here? Is there a better approach?